# Zeppelin filter on Queries

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, data-visualization, apache-zeppelin

I have been working on Apache Zeppelin for visualizing Apache Spark data, but for that I want to create self service filter to visualize data on the basis of filters. Following is my query.

```
%sql 
select * from table_name where item="${item=A,A|B|C}"
```

Q1- It creates filter but I want to show different names on filters. E.g. for A, I want my filter to display "time" but set `item=A`. Is it possible with Zeppelin?

Q2- Is it possible to give a list to select item. E.g. for `A|B|C` is it possible to give list of filter objects like `list=[A,B,C]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for can be found at https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.1/manual/dynamicform.html#select-form

It states:

```
Also you can separate option's display name and value, using 

${formName=defaultValue,option1(DisplayName)|option2(DisplayName)...}
```

[image: Example from the Zeppelin docs]